# In Perl, how can I call a method whose name I have in a string?

Tags: perl, string, oop, methods, symbols

I'm trying to write some abstract code for searching through a list of similar objects for the first one whose attributes match specific values. In order to do this, I need to call a bunch of accessor methods and check all their values one by one. I'd like to use an abstraction like this:

```
sub verify_attribute {
    my ($object, $attribute_method, $wanted_value) = @_;
    if ( call_method($object, $attribute_method) ~~ $wanted_value ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Then I can loop through a hash whose keys are accessor method names and whose values are the values I'm looking for for those attributes. For example, if that hash is called `%wanted`, I might use code like this to find the object I want:

```
my $found_object;
FINDOBJ: foreach my $obj (@list_of_objects) {
    foreach my $accessor (keys %wanted) {
        next FINDOBJ unless verify_attribute($obj, $accessor, $wanted{$accessor});
    }
    # All attrs verified
    $found_object = $obj;
    last FINDOBJ;
}
```

Of course, the only problem is that `call_method` does not exsit. Or does it? How can I call a method if I have a string containing its name? Or is there a better solution to this whole problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $found_object;
FINDOBJ: foreach my $obj (@list_of_objects) {
  foreach my $accessor (keys %wanted) {
    next FINDOBJ unless $obj->$accessor() == $wanted{$accessor};
  }
  # All attrs verified
  $found_object = $obj;
  last;
}
```

Yes, you can call methods this way. No string (or any other) eval involved.
Also, substitute `==` with `eq` or `=~` depending on the type of the data...

Or, for some extra credits, do it the functional way: (all() should really be part of List::Util!)

```
use List::Util 'first';

sub all (&@) {
  my $code = shift;
  $code->($_) || return 0 for @_;
  return 1;
}

my $match = first {
                    my $obj = $_;
                    all { $obj->$_ == $attrs{$_} }
                      keys %wanted
                  } @list_of_objects;
```

Update: Admittedly, the first solution is the less obfuscated one, so it's preferable. But as somebody answering questions, you have add a little sugar to make it interesting for yourself, too! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I just figured this out a few seoncds ago by trial and error. Cool.

Comment: I just use `List::AllUtils`. Or `Util::Any qw( :all )`. But in my example code I try to stick to the core.

Comment: I believe that for this to work you must disable strictness checks with `no strict;` (not necessarily globally) -- correct?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: For $obj->$method? Nope. Doesn't interfere with "use strict" at all. It's not a symbolic reference if that's what you#re thinking.

Comment: @tsee, thanks, that was what I was thinking.  In that case this is something I haven't come across before -- could you point me to where it's described in the Perl docs?  Thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Not sure where it's documented in the references, but "perldoc perltoot" mentions the syntax.

Comment: @tsee, I did some hunting around for "->$" in the Perl docs and the fullest explanation is in the "Method Invocation" section of perlobj.  Fair enough.  But it does seem inconsistent to me that `$func->()` and `&{$func}()` both generate "Can't use string ("f") as a subroutine ref" errors in strict mode while `$obj->$method()` doesn't...  Can anyone explain?  (Also: perlsec mentions that `$method` is not taint-checked in `$obj->$method()`...  Hmmm...)

Comment: Actually this page has some interesting discussion, although the Google Groups links seem to be down: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=139254.  My conclusion: no-one really knows the answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker => my guess as to why the `$obj->$method` syntax is ok with strict is because its just syntactic sugar for this legal construct: `$obj->can($method)->($obj)`.  whereas `$func->()` or `&{$func}()` don't have any 'strict legal' forms

Comment: Good point Eric.  Hmmm, mind you `__PACKAGE__->can($func)->()` will let you call a function by name under `use strict;`, which makes me wonder why `$func->()` isn't just syntactic sugar for that as well.  Except it doesn't work for builtins apparently.  New conclusion: Aargh.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I'm actually quite happy it doesn't work for builtins. Your example should have read `__PACKAGE__->can($methodname)->()`. The builtins are not methods. Regarding why `$func->()` doesn't work that way: $class->can($methname) returns a code reference. Thus it's actually the other way around. Executing the result of `can()` uses `$func->()`.

Comment: Eric's comment was a justification of why `$obj->$method()` works under `use strict` while `$func->()` does not; I was just trying to point out that his justification applies nearly as well to the 2nd case as to the 1st.  But I see now I was wrong, because of course `__PACKAGE__->can($func)->()` will pass the current package as parameter 1 so it's not a "plain" function call.  Since there is a `can()` for objects/classes, I don't know why there isn't a corresponding `can_func()` for plain packages (or is there?)

Answer (score 0):

Functional way is cool, but for dummies like me eval rules:

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use F;
my $f = F->new();

my $fun = 'lol'; # method of F

eval '$f->'.$fun.'() '; # call method of F, which name is in $fun var
```

F.pm

```
package F;

sub new
{
    bless {};
}


sub lol
{
    print "LoL";
}
1;
```

[root@ALT-24 root]# perl test.pl

LoL